# Display multiple lines in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview and I want to display multiple lines for the text in the cells. I tried the following code and the height changes but the text does not break and the second line does not appear. Do you have any clue about what I am doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    NSString *myString = [_menuItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UILabel *settingsLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:201];
    settingsLabel.text = myString;
    settingsLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    settingsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [settingsLabel sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *str = [_menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSLog(@"%f",size.height);
    return size.height + 10;
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard? What is the iOS version that you see the strange behaviour with the above code? I have tried your code with slight modification using storyboard in iOS 7, it looks pretty good with 2 lines of text.

Comment: Yes I am using storyboard with iOS 7 and simulating it on iPhone 5 (4 inch screen). In my project I only see 1 line of text. Maybe is sth with the label on the storyboard...

Answer (score 0):

For quick debugging, set the background colour of some views so you can see exactly where they are. For instance, how big is the label?

Rather than use `sizeToFit`, look at using `sizeThatFits:` with a size that is constrained to the available width in the cell and with a large height (the maximum reasonable height you expect). Then, use that size to set the label frame.

Better yet, use auto-layout or auto-resizing to specify that the label should grow (its height) with the cell. Then, as you have set the appropriate height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` the label should automatically resize to cater for the entire text.

Comment: The text is only 1 or 2 lines. The label is 200x30. sizeThatFits does not work. What do you mean by using auto-layout or auto-resizing?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html / https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask